Estimate Standard Errors Effortlessly
I have an unobserved variable $_$, and three observed estimates of it: $_, _, _$. The errors $_−_,_−_,_−_$ are zero mean, independent of each other and independent across $$, but the distributions are the same across $$ (although not necessarily across $$, $$, and $$). If I have $$
observations ($=1,…,$), how can I estimate the standard errors of $$, $$, and $$?
The variance of the differences between $W$ and $X$ is $\textrm{Var}(W-X) = \textrm{se}^2_W + \textrm{se}^2_X$ under the setting above when $N\rightarrow \infty$ where $\textrm{se}$ stands for standard error. The same is applied to "$X$ and $Y$", and "$Y$ and $W$".
So we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{Var}(W-X) &= \textrm{se}^2_W + \textrm{se}^2_X, \\
\textrm{Var}(X-Y) &= \textrm{se}^2_X + \textrm{se}^2_Y,\\
\textrm{Var}(Y-W) &= \textrm{se}^2_Y + \textrm{se}^2_W.
\end{aligned}
$$
The variance of the differences (left-hand side) can be calculated from observed data. Does this system of equations provide solutions for standard errors? Particularly, the inversion of this system provides an analytic solution, but is this really solved?
I am wondering especially because such a solution would have a significant implication in practical applications if it is really true: in such applications, we want to estimate/measure some underlying $Z$ (neither stationary nor fixed but can vary depending on the timing/place of measurement) by using our model/hypothesis/device $X$; in order to validate our $X$, we prepare more reliable data (ground truth or test data) as $Y$ (which makes a paired dataset $\{(X_i, Y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ where $N$ represents an observation index such as timestamps and/or location numbers, etc.); here we know that the standard deviation of the differences of $X-Y$ gives the compound standard error ($\textrm{Var}(X-Y) = \textrm{se}^2_X + \textrm{se}^2_Y$) but cannot separate into each standard error (especially interested in $\textrm{se}_X$). The system of three equations above tells that only by introducing a new variable $W$, $\textrm{se}_X$ can be estimated, and more surprisingly, $W$ does not need to depend on $Z$ (not need to measure $Z$) but can be irrelevant random numbers.
Edit
Based on @jbowman's comments, we now have two approaches to estimate the standard error of $X$. I investigated how different those approaches are and which is better in practice.
Restating the problem here, we have two paired samples of $X$ and $Y$, both observing the common signal $Z$, usually given in the table format $\{(X_i, Y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ for the sample size of $N$. In such a situation, we want to estimate the standard error of $X$. Another observation $W$ may be available.
1. Two approaches for estimating the standard error of $X$
1.1 First approach – inversion of the system of the variance of differences among three variables $X$, $Y$ and $W$
One approach is to solve the system of equations for the standard error of $X$, using the variance of the observed differences:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{Var}(W-X) &= \textrm{se}^2_W + \textrm{se}^2_X, \\
\textrm{Var}(X-Y) &= \textrm{se}^2_X + \textrm{se}^2_Y,\\
\textrm{Var}(Y-W) &= \textrm{se}^2_Y + \textrm{se}^2_W.
\end{aligned}
$$
1.2 Second approach – the use of only two variables $X$ and $Y$
The second approach, fully agnostic of the third observation $W$, is:
$$
\textrm{se}^2_X = \textrm{Var}(X) - \textrm{Cov}(X,Y).
$$
While the second approach works in the absence of $W$, I wondered how different those approaches are, especially depending on the availability of $W$.
2. Two scenarios to evaluate the two approaches
To see this, I considered two scenarios (i.e., the observed $W$ is available not).
2.1 First scenario – when $W$ can be observed
In the first scenario where $W$ is observed, our observations are as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
X &= Z + \varepsilon_X, \\
Y &= Z + \varepsilon_Y, \\
W &= Z + \varepsilon_W. \\
\end{aligned}
$$
We have the additional observation $W$ that observes the same signal $Z$ as $X$ and $Y$ observe. In this case, using the first approach, the estimate of the standard error of $X$ is
$$
\textrm{se}^2_X =: \hat{s}^2_{(1)} = a_1 \overline{\rm Var}(X-Y) + a_2 \overline{\rm Var}(Y-W) + a_3 \overline{\rm Var}(W-X),
$$
where $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ are the corresponding elements in the inverse of the design matrix in the system of equations; and $\overline{\rm Var}$ means the sample variance.
2.2 Second scenario – when $W$ cannot be observed
The second scenario is where the observed $W$ is unavailable; however we can generate a dummy $W$ that does not depend on $Z$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
X &= Z + \varepsilon_X, \\
Y &= Z + \varepsilon_Y, \\
W^\prime &= \varepsilon_W. \\
\end{aligned}
$$
By this introduction of the dummy, the solution based on the first approach is
$$
\hat{s}^2_{(2)} = a_1 \overline{\rm Var}(X-Y) + a_2 \overline{\rm Var}(Y-W^\prime) + a_3 \overline{\rm Var}(W^\prime-X).
$$
The dummy variable $W^\prime$ has no information on $Z$, but of my interest here is how differently the solution of this system behaves than the first solution $\hat{s}_{(1)}$ (and than the third solution $\hat{s}_{(3)}$, explained later).
In this second scenario, as our third solution, we can exploit the second approach:
$$
\hat{s}^2_{(3)} = \overline{\textrm{Var}}(X) - \overline{\textrm{Cov}}(X,Y).
$$
For those defined three solutions $\hat{s}_{(1)}$, $\hat{s}_{(2)}$ and $\hat{s}_{(3)}$, I investigated their dependency on the sample size $N$ and the noise level of $Z$ by computing their statistical properties (bias with respect to a true standard error of $X$ and variance of those solutions).
3. Result
The following figure shows this result: in each panel, the vertical axis is the sample size $N$ and the horizontal axis is the noise level of $Z$; in the top row, shown are the statistical bias of each solution (in terms of $\log_{10} {\rm abs(\cdot)}$) and the (reciprocal of) S/N ratio; and in the bottom row, the variance of each solution. Here, $\overline{\overline{\mathbb E}}$ and $\overline{\overline{\rm Var}}$ denote an average or variance over replications of this experiment where the number of replications is $B=10,000$.
For clarity, for the first solution $\hat{s}_{(1)}$, by introducing indices of replication $b = 1,2,\ldots,B$ and over sample $i=1,2,\ldots,N$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{\overline{\mathbb E}}[\hat{s}_{(1)}] &:= \frac{1}{B} \sum_{b=1}^B \hat{s}_{(1),b} \\
&= \frac{1}{B} \sum_{b=1}^B \sqrt{a_1 \overline{\rm Var}(X-Y)_b + a_2 \overline{\rm Var}(Y-W)_b + a_3 \overline{\rm Var}(W-X)_b},
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\overline{\rm Var}(X-Y)_b = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \{(X_{i,b} - Y_{i,b}) -\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (X_{i,b} - Y_{i,b})\}^2,
$$
and so on.
I set the true standard error of $X$ as ${\sqrt{\rm Var(\varepsilon_X)}} =4$, and with respect to this value computed the bias, and variance of $\hat{s}_{(1)}$, $\hat{s}_{(2)}$ and $\hat{s}_{(3)}$.
Seen from the figure are:

the first solution $\hat{s}_{(1)}$ (which exploits the observed $W$) only depends on the sample size $N$, but $\hat{s}_{(2)}$ and $\hat{s}_{(3)}$ (which are agnostic of the observed $W$) depend on the noise level of $Z$ as well (compare the first column vs the second and third columns);
surprisingly, $\hat{s}_{(2)}$, though this does not know the observed $W$, achieves the same performance as $\hat{s}_{(1)}$ in terms of bias (0.03 to 3.16), whereas $\hat{s}_{(3)}$, which is also not aware of $W$, works poor when the sample size is not large ($N < 1,000$) and the noise level is high ($\rm Var(\varepsilon_Z) > 10$) whose bias ranges from 10 to more than 300!
in terms of variance, $\hat{s}_{(1)}$ is robust even when the sample size is relatively small; however $\hat{s}_{(2)}$ and $\hat{s}_{(3)}$ have the same level of sensitivity both to the sample size and the noise level.


4. Conclusion
To conclude, regardless whether the observed $W$ is available, I suggest the use of the first approach (the inversion of the system of equations of the sample variance of differences). Even if $W$ is not observed, the introduction of the dummy variable $W^\prime$ seems to help estimate the standard error of $X$ as noted in the second point above.
This could be applied to the practical evaluation task where we have two samples of our estimate $X$ and the corresponding ground truth $Y$, both of which observe a common signal $Z$.
I just obtained the conclusion only by experiment but not theoretically, and hope someone (or I) will validate these findings in a theoretical aspect.

Why not just calculate the sample variances of $X$, $Y$, and $W$ directly from the data?

The context is I would like to estimate the precision (or standard errors) of $X$ which is different from the sample variance of $X$. Schematically, the standard error is shown as the standard deviation of the red ovals in the first picture (I added now) and can be seen as the standard deviation of random errors around the true value $Z=z$. On the other hand, the sample standard deviation corresponds to $s_X$ on the left panel in the second picture.

More exactly, "around the true value" corresponds to when $\mathbb E[X\mid Z=z]$ is unbiased toward $z$ (when biased, the error should distribute around $\mathbb E[X\mid Z=z]$).

I found I wrongly wrote the post, and what jbowman said is right only based on the post. In the post, the sample variance totally leads to standard error (uncertainty of $X$). What I wanted to ask was about the case where $Z$ is not fixed but variable depending on the timing of observation and/or on the location of observation and in such a case the way of the simultaneous equations from three types of measurements does work or not .

How about rephrasing your question as:  "I have an unobserved variable $z_i$, and three observed estimates of it:  $w_i, x_i, y_i$.  The errors $w_i-z_i, x_i-z_i, y_i-z_i$ are zero mean, independent of each other and independent across $i$, but the distributions are the same across $i$ (although not necessarily across $w, x, $and $y$.)  If I have $N$ observations ($i=1,\dots, N$), how can I estimate the standard errors of $w, x, $and $y$?

Thanks, that should be better. I will change my post.

The question comes down to whether or not the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
is invertible, which it is.
The full expression we are dealing with is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm{Var}(W-X) \\ \mathrm{Var}(W-Y) \\ \mathrm{Var}(X-Y)
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{se}^2_W \\ \mathrm{se}^2_X \\ \mathrm{se}^2_Y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where we know the left-hand side values and want to solve for the vector of squared standard errors. Premultiplying both sides by the inverse of the matrix above results in:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.5 & 0.5 & -0.5 \\
-0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
0.5 & -0.5 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm{Var}(W-X) \\ \mathrm{Var}(W-Y) \\ \mathrm{Var}(X-Y)
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{se}^2_W \\ \mathrm{se}^2_X \\ \mathrm{se}^2_Y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Here's an example, in R:
X <- matrix(c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1),3,3)

z <- rnorm(10000)

x <- z + rnorm(10000, 0, 0.5) # Variance 0.25
y <- z + rnorm(10000, 0, 1)   # Variance 1
w <- z + rnorm(10000, 0, 1.5) # Variance 2.25

lhs  <- c(var(x-y), var(x-w), var(y-w))

> X
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1
> solve(X,lhs)
[1] 0.2667820 0.9712982 2.2966465
>

where we can see that the estimated variances are quite accurate.
Edit in response to comments:
What happens if one of the three variables is seemingly irrelevant because it doesn't depend on $z$? We can imagine a new variable with variance equal to the old variable + the variance of $z$, constructed so that the added component cancels out the effect of adding $z$.  Consequently, we expect to see the calculated variance of the seemingly irrelevant component equal to its true variance + the variance of $z$:
w <- rnorm(10000, 0, 1.5)

lhs  <- c(var(x-y), var(x-w), var(y-w))

> solve(X,lhs)
[1] 0.2814384 0.9634355 3.2494000

... and, sure enough, the estimated variances of $x$ and $y$ are still pretty good, and the estimated variance of $w$ is approximately equal to its own variance ($2.25$) plus the variance of $z$ ($1.0$).
In fact, we don't need $z$ at all:
x <- rnorm(10000, 0, 0.5)
y <- rnorm(10000, 0, 1)
w <- rnorm(10000, 0, 1.5)

lhs  <- c(var(x-y), var(x-w), var(y-w))

> solve(X,lhs)
[1] 0.2667820 0.9712982 2.2966465

which, again, are pretty close to the true values - and identical to our original values.  If we go back to the original definitions of $w,x,$ and $y$, we can see the differences $w-x$, etc. remove $z$ from the expressions, so it is really $z$ that is irrelevant.
Edit in response to comments:
In the situation where you only have two observed variables $X$ and $Y$, we can estimate the variances of $X-Z$ and $Y-Z$ by subtracting the sample covariance of $X$ and $Y$ from the sample variances of $X$ and $Y$:
z <- rnorm(10000)
x <- z + rnorm(10000, 0, 0.5)
y <- z + rnorm(10000,0,1.5)
 
> cov(x,y)           # Estimated variance of z
[1] 1.00738
> var(x) - cov(x,y)  # Estimated variance of x - z
[1] 0.2585663
> var(y) - cov(x,y)  # Estimated variance of y - z
[1] 2.210514

which gives us reasonably good estimates of the actual variances $0.25$ and $2.25$.

Only invertibility suffices? I agree that the system seems very easy to be solved algebraically, but I am not sure if it is always true in practice. For example, let $Z$ be true wind speed time-series (non-observable), $X$ be a simulation model by which we want to estimate $Z$, and $Y$ be a ground truth, in-situ measurement of $Z$. In such a situation, if we generate, as $W$, trivial data (e.g., random numbers or just constants), does this meaningless $W$ help estimate the standard errors of $X$ and $Y$? $Z$ has no information on the true wind speeds..

Also, no need to check the rank of the system? The rank of the three by three matrix is 3, so I think the rank of the corresponding augmented coefficient matrix needs to be 3, in order for the system to have solutions. In this case, we have $(A_1 \neq 0, A_2 \neq 0,A_2 + A_3 \neq A_1)$ where $(A_1, A_2, A_3)$ is one of the three combinations of $\textrm{Var}(W-X)$, $\textrm{Var}(X-Y)$ and $\textrm{Var}(Y-W)$. That being said, I do not feel these conditions give any insight on the practical solvability (e.g. for the wind speed example above).

Invertibility of the matrix <-> the matrix is full rank.   So if you can look at the matrix and see it's invertible, you're done.  Also, what do you mean by "augmented coefficient matrix?"

I meant a matrix as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix . By regarding the matrix $B$ in the link as our left-hand side (observed vector) and setting $B = (A_1, A_2, A_3)^\top$, I checked the conditions that $A_1$ to $A_3$ should satisfy for the system to have solutions. I am now confused because on the solvability, the invertibility only involves the design matrix whereas conditions derived from the ranks of the design and its augmented matrices take into account the observed vector (left-hand side or the matrix $B$ in the link).

Thanks for the R script. So seems okay to think this generally holds? I am wondering particularly because it would have a significantly practical impact if this solution is really reasonable. In many applications (including natural/social sciences and engineering), the problem setting as we defined is very common: i.e., we want to measure/estimate some underlying, non-stationary truth $Z$ by our model/algorithm/sensor $X$. (contd)

In order to evaluate our $X$, we usually prepare more reliable (but not perfect) source as $Y$ (so-called ground truth or test data). In such a situation, by only introducing a meaningless variable $W$, both standard errors of $X$ and $Y$ can be reasonably estimated — Really? Things go so easy? So the title "Estimate Effortlessly" is true?

If you read the Wikipedia article carefully, it points out that "... the system is inconsistent (has no solutions) if the rank of the augmented matrix $A\vert B$
{ is greater than the rank of the coefficient matrix $A$."  What counts is the rank of $A$ only.  But don't forget there are other approaches.  You can make use of the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ as an estimate of the variance of $Z$, and subtract that from the sample variances of $X$ and $Y$ to get the numbers you want - you don't need to introduce a third variable at all.

I totally miscalculated about the conditions on the rank I raised (thanks for answering, but please forget about the rank). Do you mean ${\rm se}^2_X = {\rm Var}(X) - {\rm Cov}(X,Y)$ ?

Yes, I do.  See my most recent edit at the end of the answer above for an example.

That is very interesting. Is the rationale behind that approximation ${\rm Var}(Z) \simeq {\rm Cov}(X, Y)$, based on ${\rm Var}(X-Y) = {\rm Var}(X) + {\rm Var}(Y) - 2 {\rm Cov}(X,Y) = {\rm se}^2_X + {\rm se}^2_Y$, ${\rm Var}(X) = {\rm Var}(Z) +  {\rm se}^2_X$ and ${\rm Var}(Y) = {\rm Var}(Z) +  {\rm se}^2_Y$ when the observation process is additive, i.e., $X = Z + \varepsilon_X$ and $Y = Z + \varepsilon_Y$ (i.e., $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$ and their noises $\varepsilon_X,  \varepsilon_Y$ do not depend on $Z$)?

No, it's based on the definition of covariance and the fact that the two measurement errors are independent of each other.

I was able to derive that (surprising that the errors of $X$ and $Y$ seem not needed to be zero-mean). Because I wondered how the two ways (inversion of the system or variance-minus-covariance) differ and which is better, I performed an experiment and added the result in the original post. In a nutshell, the inversion of the system seems always better,  even if the third variable $W$ is unobservable, by introducing the meaningless $W$.

By the way, do you happen to know this kind of topic (the inversion method and variance-minus-covariance method, in this context) is discussed somewhere (textbooks, lectures, whatsoever)? I think these are very helpful in practical applications, but have never seen anywhere...
